# Transformar um array para string no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando converter um array para uma string e nele adicionar o "|" no inicio e no final de cada campo

Abaixo o array de exemplo

```
['', 'C170', '1', '14879', '', '1,00000', 'UN', '29,99', '0,00', '1', '060', '1407',
 'NE09', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0,00', '0', '49', '', '0,00', '0,00',
 '0,00', '99', '0,00', '0,00', '', '', '0,00', '99', '0,00', '0,00', '', '', '0,00', 
'3010107010057', '\n']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"|".join(a)
```

produz uma string com os elementos separados por "|"

```
'|C170|1|14879||1,00000|UN|29,99|0,00|1|..... 3010107010057|\n'
```

---

Juntando "|" no inicio e fim:

```
"|" +  "|".join(a) + "|"
```

ou

```
 "|%s|" %   "|".join(a)
```

dá

```
'||C170|1|14879||1,00000|UN|29,99|0,00|1|..... 3010107010057|\n|'
```

era isto que pretendes?

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo que estava precisando rsrsrs :D